# Kotlin - How to wait for multiple API calls to finish and update UI?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

I'm new to kotlin coroutines. I've been trying to run multiple API calls in parallel and then when all the calls are done update my UI and dismiss the loader, but with no success. This is my code

```
private fun getScoreForType() {
    val job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        types.forEach { type ->
            getScore(type)
        }
    }

    runBlocking {
        job.join()
        // do some ui work
        dismissLoader()
    }
}


private fun getScore(type: String) {
    val call = MyApi.getScores(type)

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<Score> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Score>, response: Response<Score>) {
            setScore(response)
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Score>, t: Throwable) {
        }

    })
}
```

I've also tried using async and awaitAll but couldn't make it work either. The loader is always dismissed before all the calls are done. Any help on how I could make this work would be much appreciated

Comment: Is this helpful? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/parallel-multiple-network-calls-using-kotlin-coroutines/

Comment: This doesn't help in my case, because I don't want to get the data from the response but just dismiss the loader after all calls are done

Comment: I think the problem is with your `getScore` function because it use a callback so it does not wait the call to complete. Better change the api call to coroutine too. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/retrofit-with-kotlin-coroutine-in-android/

Comment: You are right. I changed the call to a coroutine and now it's working fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Flow and collectData it will works as LiveData.

For example:

val myIntFlow = MutableStateFlow(-1)

Try something like;

in ViewModelMethods

```
private fun getScoreForType() {
It goes first:
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        types.forEach { type ->
            getScore(type)
        }
 // it means to change value of flow

myIntFlow.value = 1
    }
    // Now collect data in fragment to change UI

}
// in fragment like:
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
// flow will be triggered, on every changed value
viewModel.myIntFlow.collect {
viewModel.methodFromViewModelToChangeUI()
dissmisloader()
myIntFlow.value = -1
}
}


// try the same here as you wish

private fun getScore(type: String) {
    val call = MyApi.getScores(type)

    call.enqueue(object : Callback<Score> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Score>, response: Response<Score>) {
            setScore(response)
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Score>, t: Throwable) {
        }

    })
}
```